# MySQL table structure, do I need a primary key?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a table in MySQL using Innodb. The table will contain measurements from several locations. Roughly the data that should be stored is:

- monitor_id - Id of the monitor (indexed)
- time - time of the measurement, resolution in seconds (indexed)
- value - current value

In time, there might be many million new rows every day.

My questions are:

1. Do I need a Primary Key? For the sake of my application I don't need a PK, but the database might? If so, is it a bad idea to use BigInt?
2. Is it a bad idea to store the time as a MySQL DateTime? Or should I use a integer to store a unix_timestamp? Does it really matter in the long run? This column will be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yep. its better to have some id as PK. Autoincrement (BigInt is ok)
2. Int is better for highload. Much less data to store (& index) but more logic in app (not in queries).

Comment: Isn't it more beneficial to save the storage the PK will add? Considering that it will need to be a BigInt I mean...

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use primary key . There have no reason to avoid primary key

[Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html) Says

> The primary key for a table represents the column or set of columns
>   that you use in your most vital queries. It has an associated index,
>   for fast query performance. Query performance benefits from the NOT
>   NULL optimization, because it cannot include any NULL values. With the
>   InnoDB storage engine, the table data is physically organized to do
>   ultra-fast lookups and sorts based on the primary key column or
>   columns.

2. If you want to store a specific value you should use a datetime field otherwise you should use time stamp . For example you want update a record in  future the its datatype should timestamp because timestamp will change automatic for you

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner my solution would be to use a combination of the existing columns as a primary key. So long as you use enough columns which varies enough that every row becomes unique.

In this case you might need all 3 columns to be used as primary identifiers in order for it to work out. But it would save you from having to create an entire column just for the sake of a primary since you seemed worried about space.