# High traffic table, optimal indexes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a monitoring table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `monitor_data` (
    `monitor_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `monitor_data_time` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `monitor_data_value` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `monitor_id_data_time` (`monitor_id`, `monitor_data_time`),
    INDEX `monitor_data_time` (`monitor_data_time`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This is a very high traffic table with potentially thousands of rows every minute. Each row belongs to a monitor and contains a value and time (unix_timestamp)

I have three issues:

1.
Suddenly, after a number of months in dev, the table suddenly became very slow. Queries that previously was done under a second could now take up to a minute. I'm using standard settings in my.cnf since this is a dev machine, but the behavior was indeed very strange to me.

2.
I'm not sure that I have optimal indexes. A "normal" query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(md.monitor_data_time), monitor_data_value
FROM monitor_data md 
WHERE md.monitor_id = 165
    AND md.monitor_data_time >= 1484076760
    AND md.monitor_data_time <= 1487271199
ORDER BY md.monitor_data_time ASC;
```

A EXPLAIN on the query above looks like this:

```
id;select_type;table;type;possible_keys;key;key_len;ref;rows;Extra
1;SIMPLE;md;range;monitor_id_data_time,monitor_data_time;monitor_id_data_time;8;\N;149799;Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

What do you think about the indexes?

3.
If I leave out the DISTINCT in the query above, I actually get duplicate rows even though there aren't any duplicate rows in the table. Any explanation to this behavior?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 1:**

New suggestion on table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `monitor_data_test` (
`monitor_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`monitor_data_time` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`monitor_data_value` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`monitor_data_time`, `monitor_id`),
INDEX `monitor_data_time` (`monitor_data_time`)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Note about UPDATE 1: the secondary index is redundant with the proposed primary key; adding that is a waste. For the predicates of the query given in the question, we'd prefer to have an index with `monitor_id` is the leading column (as I suggested in my answer.) If there's some reason the cluster key doesn't have `(monitor_id,monitor_data_time)` as the leading columns, then we'd want a *covering* index as a secondary index, `(monitor_Id,monitor_data_time,monitor_data_value)`.  There are specific reasons for my recommendations; we're not just throwing stuff at the wall to see what sticks.

Answer (score 2):

*What do you think about the indexes?*

The index on `(monitor_id,monitor_data_time)` seems appropriate for the query. That's suited to an index range scan operation, very quickly eliminating boatloads of rows that need to be examined.

Better would be a *covering* index that also includes the `monitor_data_value` column. Then the query could be satisfied entirely from the index, without a need to lookup pages from the data table to get `monitor_data_value`.

And even better would be having the InnoDB cluster key be the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY on the columns, rather than incurring the overhead of the synthetic row identifier that InnoDB creates when an appropriate index isn't defined.

If I wasn't allowing duplicate `(monitor_id, monitor_data_time)` tuples, then I'd define the table with a UNIQUE index on those non-nullable columns.

```
 CREATE TABLE `monitor_data` 
 ( `monitor_id`         INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 , `monitor_data_time`  INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 , `monitor_data_value` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL
 , UNIQUE KEY `monitor_id_data_time` (`monitor_id`, `monitor_data_time`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

or equivalent, specify PRIMARY in place of UNIQUE and remove the identifier

```
 CREATE TABLE `monitor_data` 
 ( `monitor_id`         INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 , `monitor_data_time`  INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 , `monitor_data_value` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL
 , PRIMARY KEY (`monitor_id`, `monitor_data_time`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

---

*Any explanation to this behavior?*

If the query (shown in the question) returns a different number of rows with the DISTINCT keyword, then there *must* be duplicate `(monitor_id,monitor_data_time,monitor_data_value)` tuples in the table.  There's nothing in the table definition that guarantees us that there aren't duplicates.

There are a couple of other possible explanations, but those explanations are all related to rows being added/changed/removed, and the queries seeing  different snapshots, transaction isolation levels, yada, yada.  If the data isn't changing, then there are duplicate rows.

---

A PRIMARY KEY constraint (or UNIQUE KEY constraint non-nullable columns) would guarantee us uniqueness.

Note that `DISTINCT` is a keyword in the SELECT list. It's not a function. The DISTINCT keyword applies to *all* expressions in the SELECT list. The parens around `md.monitor_date_time` are superfluous.

Leaving the `DISTINCT` keyword out would eliminate the need for the "Using filesort" operation. And that can be expensive for large sets, particularly when the set is too large to sort in memory, and the sort has to spill to disk.

It would be much more efficient to have guaranteed uniqueness, omit the DISTINCT keyword, and return rows in order by the index, preferably the cluster key.

Also, the secondary index `monitor_data_time` doesn't benefit this query. (There may be other queries that can make effective use of the index, though one suspects that those queries would also make effective use of a composite index that had `monitor_data_time` as the leading column.

Comment: @gregoff:  Seems like you asked an earlier question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794612/mysql-table-structure-do-i-need-a-primary-key   whether this table should have a PRIMARY KEY. If the `(monitor_id,monitor_data_time)` tuple is unique, yes, this should be the composite cluster key of the table. That tuple can be defined as the PRIMARY KEY of the table. Or, given that those two columns are defined NOT NULL, declaring a UNIQUE KEY would give the same effect. For this table, it's not necessary to define an extra column to serve as a surrogate key.

Comment: Yes, but I created a new question since this one was far more detailed with more info.
 
I thank you for your input! It sounds like I should place a bet on creating a combined PK since the first two columns should be unique together anyway.
 
Updated my question above with a suggestion of a new structure (UPDATE 1). Would that work better? I really am looking for the best long term solution since this table potentially will hold many millions of rows. Should I also add a single index on the column monitor_data_value?

Comment: I accedently posted a edit on your post when I was supposed to do it on my own. Please disregard.

Comment: "Update 1" is not good for two reasons:  The second index is redundant since it is a leading subset of the first.  The columns in the first index are not in the best order for the query.  (See my Answer.)

Comment: Ok, thanks again! A small note, by dropping my previous indexes and creating the two column index made my dev database go from 800+ MB to a little over 300...

Comment: @gregoff: If we define a PRIMARY KEY, or a UNIQUE KEY on NOT NULL column(s), InnoDB can use that as the *cluster key* for the table. And the cluster key I proposed would be ideal for this table. (The only chance we have of getting better performance with a different index would be the corner case of a very strange data distribution, i.e. all rows with _time between 1484076760 and 1487271199 have the same value of monitor_id. If not defined as the cluster key, then at least a secondary *covering* index on `(monitor_id,monitor_data_time,monitor_data_value)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(md.monitor_data_time), monitor_data_value
```

is the same as

```
SELECT DISTINCT md.monitor_data_time, monitor_data_value
```

That is, the pair is distinct.  It does *not* dedup just the `time`.  Is that what you want?

If you are trying to de-dup *just* the `time`, then do something like

```
SELECT time, AVG(value)
    ...
    GROUP BY time;
```

For optimal performance of

```
WHERE md.monitor_id = 165
AND md.monitor_data_time >= 14840767604 ...
```

you need

```
PRIMARY KEY (monitor_id, monitor_data_time)
```

and it *must* be in that order.  The opposite order is *much* less useful.  The guiding principle is:  Start with the '=', then move on to the 'range'.  More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Do you have 4 billion `monitor_id` values?  `INT` takes 4 bytes; consider using a smaller datatype.

Do you have other queries that need optimizing?  It is better to design the index(es) after gather all the important queries.

**Why PK**

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data.  That is, the data is an ordered list of triples: `(id, time, value)` stored in a B+Tree.  Locating `id = 165 AND time = 1484076760` is a basic operation of a BTree.  And it is *very* fast.  Then scanning forward (that's the "+" part of "B+Tree") until `time = 1487271199` is a very fast operation of "next row" in this ordered list.  Furthermore, since `value` is right there with the `id` and `time`, there is no extra effort to get the values.

You can't scan the requested rows any faster.  But it requires `PRIMARY KEY`.  (OK, `UNIQUE(id, time)` would be 'promoted' to be the PK, but let's not confuse the issue.)

Contrast...  Given an index `(time, id)`, it would do the scan over the dates fine, but it would have to skip over any entries where `id != 165`  But it would have to read all those rows to discover they do not apply.  A lot more effort.

Since it is unclear what you *intended* by `DISTINCT`, I can't continue this detailed discussion of how that plays out.  Suffice it to say:  The possible rows have been found; now some kind of secondary pass is needed to do the `DISTINCT`.  (It may not even need to do a sort.)

Comment: Thanks for your input!
 
Why does the primary key need exactly in that order? Simply because that monitor_id probably is more narrower than monitor_data_time ?

Comment: No.  There is a single `id`, and the records for that `id` will be adjacent by `time`.  Think of a dentist's office (that still uses paper files).  To find _your_ records for _last year_, it is better to have a folder with your records chronologically sorted, than to have everybody's records comingled, then have to search last year looking for just your records.

Comment: Good explaination! Thanks!